# TCL convert list to string with new line every X list elements

Tags: string, list, tcl

I have a large list which I put in a file without any line break:

```
puts $output_file ", [format " %s" [join $elems ","]]"
```

however I need to insert a line break every 8 elements, since the resulting file is not interpreted correctly.

I wonder if there is some kind of built in function to do that?

If not I was thinking about a procedure returning a string with line breaks or a function writing to file every 8 elements.

anyone had the same problem?

Is there something like this in TCL : [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python?rq=1)

thanks.

Comment: should each line end with a comma or not?

Comment: no it is not necessary,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lrange` command to get the required range of list elements and loop it through till the end.

```
set input {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12} 
for {set startIdx 0} {$startIdx<[llength $input]} {incr startIdx 8} {
    set endIdx [expr {$startIdx+7}]
    puts [lrange $input $startIdx $endIdx]
}
```

**Output :**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

Even if the `endIdx` exceeds the actual size of the list, it is not an issue. This is the reason, when the loop runs for the second time, the `endIdx` will be 15 and `Tcl` will return list elements only up to 11th index element.

Comment: thank you that, how ever the elements need to be separated by commas, is that possible with lrange?

Comment: puts ", [format " %s" [join [lrange $liste $startIdx $endIdx] ","]]" does work thank you!

Comment: Simple `[join [lrange $liste $startIdx $endIdx] ","]` will work too... without format.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to define a command that, when run as a coroutine, will return parts ("chunks") of a list, one at a time. This command takes a list, a length, and an optional starting index (default 0). When it has exhausted the list, it returns an empty list forever.

```
proc chunk {list n {i 0}} {
    yield
    set m [expr {$n - 1}]
    while 1 {
        yield [lrange $list $i $i+$m]
        incr i $n
    }
}
```

Create the coroutine command, providing the list and the length:

```
coroutine nextchunk chunk $input 8
```

Use it like this:

```
for {set chunk [nextchunk]} {[llength $chunk] > 0} {set chunk [nextchunk]} {
    puts [join $chunk ", "]
}
```

Documentation: [coroutine](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/coroutine.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm), [yield](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/coroutine.htm)

Comment: Nice solution, but I saw this error message: `invoked "break" outside of a loop`

Comment: @glennjackman: it worked for me in `tkcon` because it meddles with the exceptions. In other shells, that error message appears. A reminder to always test code in different shells... I've posted an alternative solution that works in all three shells.